# Where to find the legend for Corine Land Cover Change

Tags: qgis, legend

I have successfully downloaded both the Corine Land Cover 2018 and Corine Land Cover Change 2012-2018 data and opened them up in QGIS. However, there only seems to be one legend for both datasets. How can I find a legend that is specific to the Change dataset which tells me which class has transitioned to which class.

Comment: By the documentation the change data is divided into two files "In order to keep 8 bit resolution for raster change layers, they are divided into two files - representing consumption (from) and formation (to) part of change."

Answer (score 0):

you can find the CORINE land cover classes here: https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2/corine-land-cover-classes-and/clc_legend.csv
When you download the vector of CORINE LC changes, the legend will indicate which class has been changed to which class. So you only need to use the key above to understand the change.